# Should all these "in-place-editing" tags be merged as synonyms?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

[When requesting the two tags "inplace" / "in-place" be merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151933) I discovered this bunch of tags all with similar names that should be unified:

- [edit-in-place](/questions/tagged/edit-in-place) **× 55**
- [inplace-editing](/questions/tagged/inplace-editing) **× 26**
- [in-place-editor](/questions/tagged/in-place-editor) **× 10**
- [in-place-edit](/questions/tagged/in-place-edit) **× 6**

Comment: Given that most of them don't have all that  many questions, why not spend some time editing them, addressing all other issues as well? Just re-tag them as Gilles has done for your previous question.

Comment: Oh just because I have other things of my own to get on with but I thought bringing this to light for someone to fix would benefit the site and its users. I don't actually use any of these tags myself.

Comment: Note that `in_place_edit` is a Rails plugin, not just a generic term.  Some of those questions are about that plugin specifically.

Comment: @blahdiblah: It sounds like that one especially needs a tag wiki in that case.

Comment: @blahdiblah: Well I was gonna make a tagwiki for it but searching I couldn't find a Rails plugin by that name. What I found is called [`in_place_editing`](https://github.com/rails/in_place_editing), which is closer to our 2nd most popular tag in this list, not the least popular tag.